# Jekyll Import Syntax Highlighting Colour Scheme

Tags: html, css, sass, colors, jekyll

The syntax highlighting for Jekyll Minima theme is defined in the file `_sass/_syntax-highlighting.scss`.

A snippet of code copied from that file is:

```
  .c     { color: #998; font-style: italic } // Comment
  .err   { color: #a61717; background-color: #e3d2d2 } // Error
  .k     { font-weight: bold } // Keyword
  .o     { font-weight: bold } // Operator
  .cm    { color: #998; font-style: italic } // Comment.Multiline
  .cp    { color: #999; font-weight: bold } // Comment.Preproc
  .c1    { color: #998; font-style: italic } // Comment.Single
  .cs    { color: #999; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic } // Comment.Special
  .gd    { color: #000; background-color: #fdd } // Generic.Deleted
  .gd .x { color: #000; background-color: #faa } // Generic.Deleted.Specific
  .ge    { font-style: italic } // Generic.Emph
```

I want to change the colour scheme, for example, to the Palenight theme. One way to do this is to copy the code from `_syntax-highlighting.scss` to my site repository and change the colours manually.

What is the conventional way to do this in Jekyll? Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this *is* the conventional way. You copy the file from the theme and override it locally