# Jekyll 4.3.2: How to set alternate color scheme for code highlighting

Tags: sass, jekyll, kramdown

I'm trying to simply change a few things regarding the code highlighting in my Jekyll pages on github and have been unable to get anything to work.

After reading a lot of pages/questions, I've tried:

1. Adding various random seeming scss files (_base.scss, _highlights.scss, _syntax_highlighting.scss)

```
.highlight {
  ...
}
```

2. Adding main.css and syntax.css

```
---
# Some Jekyll nonsense... (not needed in other scss files).
---

@import "syntax";
```

3. Adding the following snippet to _config.yml

```
# Jekyll 3 now only supports Kramdown for Markdown
kramdown:
  # Use GitHub flavored markdown, including triple backtick fenced code blocks
  input: GFM
  # Jekyll 3 and GitHub Pages now only support rouge for syntax highlighting
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    # Use existing pygments syntax highlighting css
    css_class: 'highlight'

sass:
  style: compressed
```

I've looked at:
[Jekyll Import Syntax Highlighting Colour Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802748/jekyll-import-syntax-highlighting-colour-scheme)
But this didn't work when I tried it *and* isn't what I'm after (just c&p whole files doesn't feel like real solution to me). I suspect this answer is out-of-date now but I have no way to know for sure.

The main issue is that I've never found documentation that just explains, to a Jekyll n00b, what the basic processing steps are. So I've got zero intuition of what to change were to affect things.

For example:

1. Do I need to copy all of the theme I'm using (just-the-docs) before any modifications will take effect?
2. Can I add just one `.scss` file and have the system inherit the remaining ones?
3. Is adding `main.css` enough to trigger it being processed or do I need to change how I run Jekyll?
4. Is the fact I'm using the `just-the-docs` theme messing up my ability to change code highlighting?

All in all it's very poor documented and most "answers" to questions I've found boil down to telling people to cut & paste X into Y (and since Jekyll seems to have had some breaking changes between versions a lot of these don't age well).

The pages are at:
https://github.com/hagbard/the-flogger-manual/tree/main/docs
https://hagbard.github.io/the-flogger-manual/

I'm just using standard triple-backticks + language to specify a code block (though some pages suggest other approaches, but again I suspect they are out-of-date).

Ideally I'd want to be able to easily download and install one of the color schemes in:
http://jwarby.github.io/jekyll-pygments-themes/languages/javascript.html

but even just getting one small thing to change in the syntax highlighting would probably be enough to get me started.